# How to use javascript Text To Speech on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I am trying to play a simple Text to Speech using ResponsiveVoice (http://responsivevoice.org/). It is working perfectly fine on desktop browsers. But it is not working on mobile browsers.
How can I make this work?